# Getting an unknown key error while transfer some EOS form one account to another

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, permissions

I have written an action transfer in my contract which is as below

```
// @abi action
void second::transfer( account_name from,
                      account_name to,
                      asset        quantity,
                      string      memo  )
{
    eosio_assert( from != to, "cannot transfer to self" );
    require_auth( from );
    eosio_assert( is_account( to ), "to account does not exist");
    auto sym = quantity.symbol.name();
    stats statstable( _self, sym );
    const auto& st = statstable.get( sym );

    require_recipient( from );
    require_recipient( to );

    eosio_assert( quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity" );
    eosio_assert( quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity" );
    eosio_assert( quantity.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch" );
    eosio_assert( memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes" );

    //print("balance of account from before transaction______",from.balance.amount);

    print("before transaction ______________________________account before_____________________________________________");
    asset value;
    printBalance(from,value);
    printBalance(to,value);
    sub_balance( from, quantity );
    add_balance( to, quantity, from );
    printBalance(from,value);
    printBalance(to,value);
    print("transfer _____________________account after________________________________________________________");

}
```

My contract name is second and I set the contract with my account name firstname , I also have a second account secondname and i set the permission as given

```
cleos --wallet-url http://wallet:5555 -u http://server:7777 set account permission firstname active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS5BbbeRJizvAUq27RLFXWtabMfVgs9MjYUBJ8Y5cwvoDCYnnPyp","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"firstname","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p firstname
```

I had issued 10000.0000 EOS to account firstname, but when I send EOS from firstname to secondname using the following command

```
cleos --wallet-url http://wallet:5555 -u http://server:7777 push action firstname transfer '[ "firstname", "secondname", "1.0001 EOS", "message"]' -p firstname
```

I get the following error :
***845758ms thread-0   main.cpp:2350   main  ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10) condition: assertion failed: unable to find key***

my wallet is unlocked and running on port 5555 and nodeos running on port 7777. **Am I  doing something wrong while setting permission** ?

PS: I am a little bit unclear about setting permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not relate to account permissions. Permission errors would typically look like this:

```
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"player","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

This error `main.cpp:2350 main ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10) condition: assertion failed: unable to find key` indicates an issue in your smart contract cpp code. 
My guess would be that it is unable to find your token symbol here:

```
const auto& st = statstable.get( sym );
```

Are you sure you have created a token before trying to find it by symbol? How does your statstable and index declarations look like? Can you check if this table contains the symbol you are trying to `.get()`?

Comment: First I created the tokens and then  I  try to issue the token to  a account than this error occur .