# Using transfer to send tokens within a smart contract results in "unable to find key"

Tags: permissions, c++, transfer

This is my example code deployed on myaccount

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/currency.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

class exampleSendToken : public eosio::contract
{
public:
  using contract::contract;
  exampleSendToken(account_name caller) : contract(caller) {}

  /// @abi action
  void send()
  {
    action(permission_level{_self, N(active)}, N(eosio.token), N(transfer),
           currency::transfer{.from=_self, .to=N(myotheraccount), .quantity=asset(1), .memo="sent by contract"}).send();

  }
};

EOSIO_ABI( exampleSendToken, (send))
```

I used this line to give myaccount@eosio.code the permissions to use active and initiate the transfer.

`cleos set account permission myaccount active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS7Qcpqm8....3T9amgDJu8v","weight": 1}], "accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p myaccount@owner`

When I call `cleos --print-response push action myaccount send [] -p myaccount`

the returned error is
`Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: unable to find key
pending console output:`

The both accounts exist and the full returned response asks for a key that I have in my wallet

`"required_keys": [
    "EOS7Qcpqm8....3T9amgDJu8v"`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue (with help from a related thread [1859](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/getting-an-unknown-key-error-while-transfer-some-eos-form-one-account-to-another)).
Please correct me if I am wrong but on jungle testnet the CORE_SYMBOL is set to SYS but there is no SYS token available. The "key" therefore does not refer to a cryptographic key but a key in a database.

The solution is to define the asset correctly to use EOS:

```
asset(1, S(4, EOS))
```